# Execute script sourced to an external file loaded from AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is a very common question in here related to AJAX, but I can't seem to find one for my case, because most of them used jQuery, and other reasons. Probably mine isn't efficient/recommended, but either way, here we go.

I have a button [let's say we have a reference to it for the sake of it called `btn`].

It listens for a clicking event. When the user clicks the button, it makes an AJAX request to a .txt file present in the same directory the main HTML/CSS/JS file is. Let's call it `test.txt`.

Now, it changes the `<html>`'s innerHTML(not the head/body, the html), and the innerHTML is the response from the AJAX request.

`test.txt` holds HTML code. And within that HTML code there's `<script src="another-js-file.js">`. 
This doesn't get executed, this is the problem.

Before you scream at me **INNERHTML DOESN'T EXECUTE ANY SCRIPTS** I know that. I've seen other answers saying to create a `<script>` tag within a div that's within yet another div, but it doesn't seem to work with external js files, and the solutions indeed used innerHTML.

Okay, here's a sketch:

```
 btn.onclick = function(){
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState = XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
   }
   xhr.open("GET", "./test.txt");
   xhr.send();
   }
```

Where `test.txt` holds:

```
<head>
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
   <script src="another-js-file.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

No jQuery.

Comment: _No jQuery._ 

Comment: Yeah it's redundant to use a 40KB library just for AJAX. I'm all for vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

I found that by creating a script element and setting its source to "another-file.js" like this worked:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "test.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
THIS GOES AFTER document.documentElement.innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your initial XHR request you wrote:

```
if(xhr.readyState = XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
```

This should actually be triple === not the single one.

Add this function to your initial JS file where you make the XHR request,

```
function setInnerHtml(el, html) {
  el.innerHTML = html;
  // Get all the scripts from the new HTML
  const scripts = el.querySelectorAll('script');

  // Loop through all the scripts
  for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
  {
    // Create a new script
    const s = document.createElement('script');

    // Go through all the attributes on the script
    for (let j = 0; j < scripts[i].attributes.length; j++) {
      const a = scripts[i].attributes[j];
      // Add each attribute to the new script
      s.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
    }

    // Incase there is code inside the script tag
    // Example: <script>alert</script>
    s.innerHTML = scripts[i].innerHTML;

    // Append the new script to the head (you could change this to the end of the body as well)
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  }
}
```

Then when you go to set the innerHTML of the root document object, use the above function instead.

```
if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    setInnerHtml(document.documentElement, this.responseText);
}
```

Comment: May I ask why did you add the name and value attributes to the script tag? Also, the single equal inside the if statement was an honest mistake, I did write 3 equal signs inside my project.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just noticed your comment now.  But script tags can contain attributes such as "crossorigin", "integrity", etc. You can view more about the usage of these attributes for scripts here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script.  Although in your simple example the script tag inside your text file did not contain attributes, I thought it would be good practice to add code that handled that just incase.